# Price calculator for a dispensary

Tags: java, beginner

I'm making an out the door calculator for my dispensary. As it stands now the program works 100%, im planning on adding a GUI and such in the future but right now im focused on not have a god class and splitting stuff up into methods for less repetition. I want to be able to get gramPrice, eighthPrice, quarterPrice, halfPrice, and ouncePrice, into a single array called weightPrices[] using a method. Not sure how to create a method that intakes stuff from my variable class file i get issues with taking static out of my methods when I try to call in my main file. I'm probably wording everything terribly but here is what I got going on.

This is the first part of my main class file.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main extends method {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    prices priceList = new prices();

    System.out.print("Please enter a desired Price: ");
    if (reader.hasNextInt() == true) {
        priceList.desiredPrice = getDesired(reader.nextInt());

    }

    System.out.print("Enter Price Point (5, 8, 10): ");
    if (reader.hasNextInt() == true) {
        priceList.pricePoint = reader.nextInt();
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    reader.close();

    if (priceList.pricePoint == 5) {
        
        priceList.gramPrice = getGramPrice(priceList.fivePerGram[0]);
        priceList.eighthPrice = getEighthPrice(priceList.fivePerGram[1]);
        priceList.quarterPrice = getQuarterPrice(priceList.fivePerGram[2]);
        priceList.halfPrice = getHalfPrice(priceList.fivePerGram[3]);
        priceList.ouncePrice = getOuncePrice(priceList.fivePerGram[4]);

        priceList.gramWeight = (priceList.desiredPrice / priceList.gramPrice);
        priceList.eighthWeight = (priceList.desiredPrice / priceList.eighthPrice);
        priceList.quarterWeight = (priceList.desiredPrice / priceList.quarterPrice);
        priceList.halfWeight = (priceList.desiredPrice / priceList.halfPrice);
        priceList.ounceWeight = (priceList.desiredPrice / priceList.ouncePrice);

        double weightList[] = { priceList.gramWeight, priceList.eighthWeight, priceList.quarterWeight, priceList.halfWeight, priceList.ounceWeight };

        double maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weightList).max().getAsDouble();
        maxWeight = round(maxWeight, 2);
```

This is my methods class file

```
import java.math.*;
public class method {

prices priceList = new prices();

public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}

public static double getDesired(int input) {
    double result = Double.valueOf(input);
    result /= 1.16;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getGramPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 1;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getEighthPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 3.5;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getQuarterPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 7;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getHalfPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 14;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;      
}

public static double getOuncePrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 28;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getGramWeight() {
    double result = 0;
    
    return result;
}


}
```

and my variables class file

```
public class prices {

int pricePoint = 0;
double desiredPrice = 0.0;
double fivePerGram[] = { 5, 15, 25, 40, 80 };
double eightPerGram[] = { 8, 25, 45, 85, 160 };
double tenPerGram[] = { 10, 35, 65, 120, 225 };
double weightFormat[] = { 1, 3.5, 7, 14, 28 };

//double[] weightPrices = new double[5];

double gramPrice = 0;
double eighthPrice = 0;
double quarterPrice = 0;
double halfPrice = 0;
double ouncePrice = 0;

double gramWeight = 0;
double eighthWeight = 0;
double quarterWeight = 0;
double halfWeight = 0;
double ounceWeight = 0;





}
```

Any input would be great. This is probably the most ive gotten into java as far as OOP and such so any feedback helps

Comment: What is the `method` in `public class main extends method`? The braces don't match — are you missing some code?

Comment: method is the name of my class file that holds all my methods. I extend main to it to call everything within that class file. The second block of code is the method file that im extending to. As for the first block of code my "main" class, its only the first few lines as its very repetitive.

Comment: In the method class there is a lot of redundant code

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for being brave enough to offer your code for review.

With all due respect,
the design decision to use identifiers like
gramPrice, eighthPrice, ... , halfPrice
seems like a mistake.

If you can express prices as y = m * x + b,
so price is cost per gram plus fixed transaction cost,
feel free to do that.
(Perhaps with some non-linear rounding up to nearest
convenient currency unit.)

If your marketing approach requires arbitrary
prices, then fine.
But please don't bake that into the code.
Rather, store quantities and prices in a .CSV
or similar spreadsheet.
Write a getter that accepts `.125` or `.5`,
returning the corresponding price.

---

There's a JSR that tackled conversion factors,
such as ~ 28.35 g / oz.
There might be some pieces in there
that you wish to take advantage of:

https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement

---

I see many [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)),
with no comments,
such as `5`, `1.16`, `3.5`, and so on.
(Also, it seems odd that 28.35 g == 28 g.)

Turn each magic number
into a `MANIFEST_CONSTANT`
to make things self-explanatory.

---

I can't imagine that `getGramWeight()`
does what you want it to do.

Write some unit tests.
They will help to make such errors apparent.

---

Follow the usual naming convention,
calling your class `Prices` (initial cap).

You initialize several variables to zero.
Consider boxing them (so `double` becomes `Double`)
and initializing to NULL.
The advantage is to trigger an immediate
error when you accidentally do arithmetic
with it, rather than propagating bad results
around which you'll need to later debug.

Comment: So, to all who read, the issue is i get customers that come in with a specific dollar amount they want to spend. I also have several price points for products, with each price point have specific breaks in which you get it cheaper / gram as you buy more. The program takes into account my 16% tax rate which is the 1.16, also the weight "breakpoints" are 1gram, 3.5grams, 7grams, 14grams, and 28grams. Each breakpoint has a different price/gram. I have improved the entire program into a GUI program in 1 class file. Will post the updated program soon! I have ironed out many problems

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Makes sense. Perhaps what you're looking for is a function that maps from "I want to spend N dollars" to "here is an M gram product that is perfect for you!". You might only need two or three parameters to express that -- fewer than the long .CSV spreadsheet or long source code we had considered. I assume that market conditions change as the months go by, so the parameters will be updated fairly often.