# Price Calculator for Dispensary (UPDATE)

Tags: java

This is my new code for a calculator Ive been working on. I ditched the idea of multiple class files as soon as I started working on the GUI. Just looking for some feedback on if im doing something weird or wrong. Thanks for any input. The program works, but not sure if its effiecient or conventional or anything. Im planning on making it more variable with a variable tax rate for different locations and such, so more work to be done...but heres what i got.

Original Code: [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278202/price-calculator-for-a-dispensary?noredirect=1#comment551052_278202)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

static int pricePoint = 0;
static double desiredPrice = 0.0;
static double fivePerGram[] = { 5, 15, 25, 40, 80 };
static double eightPerGram[] = { 8, 25, 45, 85, 160 };
static double tenPerGram[] = { 10, 35, 65, 120, 225 };
static double weightFormat[] = { 1, 3.5, 7, 14, 28 };

static double maxWeight = 0;

static double gramPrice = 0;
static double eighthPrice = 0;
static double quarterPrice = 0;
static double halfPrice = 0;
static double ouncePrice = 0;

static double gramWeight = 0;
static double eighthWeight = 0;
static double quarterWeight = 0;
static double halfWeight = 0;
static double ounceWeight = 0;

static double breakpoint = 0;
static double neededGrams = 0;
static double newBreak = 0;
static double underDesired = 0;

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel middlePanel = new JPanel();

static JTextField inputField = new JTextField();

JButton calculateButton = new JButton("Calculate");

JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Desired Price");
JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Grams Needed: ");
JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");

static JLabel weightOutput = new JLabel("0");

static JRadioButton fiveButton = new JRadioButton("5 / g");
static JRadioButton eightButton = new JRadioButton("8 / g");
static JRadioButton tenButton = new JRadioButton("10 / g");

Gui() {
    this.setSize(420, 420);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setResizable(false);

    ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(fiveButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(eightButton);
    radioButtonGroup.add(tenButton);

    fiveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
    fiveButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    fiveButton.setForeground(Color.white);
    fiveButton.setFocusable(false);
    
    eightButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
    eightButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    eightButton.setForeground(Color.white);
    eightButton.setFocusable(false);
    
    tenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
    tenButton.setBackground(Color.black);
    tenButton.setForeground(Color.white);
    tenButton.setFocusable(false);
    
    outputLabel.setBounds(125, 0, 200, 200);
    outputLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sams", Font.BOLD, 20));
    outputLabel.setForeground(Color.black);

    weightOutput.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    weightOutput.setBounds(140, 130, 100, 100);
    weightOutput.setFont(new Font("Comic Sams", Font.BOLD, 40));
    weightOutput.setVisible(false);
    weightOutput.setForeground(Color.green);

    inputLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
    inputLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
    inputLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sams", Font.BOLD, 11));
    inputLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 10));

    inputField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 20));
    inputField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

    calculateButton.setFont(new Font("Comic Sams", Font.PLAIN, 10));
    calculateButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 75));
    calculateButton.setFocusable(false);
    calculateButton.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    calculateButton.addActionListener(this);

    topPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
    leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    leftPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    leftPanel.add(calculateButton);
    leftPanel.add(inputLabel);
    leftPanel.add(inputField);
    leftPanel.add(emptyLabel);
    leftPanel.add(fiveButton);
    leftPanel.add(eightButton);
    leftPanel.add(tenButton);

    middlePanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
    middlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(370, 320));
    middlePanel.add(outputLabel);
    middlePanel.add(weightOutput);
    middlePanel.setLayout(null);

    this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.pack();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gui frame = new Gui();

}

public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}

public static double getDesired(int d) {
    double result = Double.valueOf(d);
    result /= 1.16;
    return result;
}

public static double getGramPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 1;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getEighthPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 3.5;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getQuarterPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 7;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getHalfPrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 14;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getOuncePrice(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    result = input / 28;
    result = round(result, 2);
    return result;
}

public static double getBreakpoint(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (input < weightFormat[i]) {
            continue;
        } else if (input >= weightFormat[i]) {
            result = weightFormat[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public static double getNeededGrams(double input) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (breakpoint == 1) {
            result = gramWeight;
            if (input > 1 && input <= 1.99) {
                underDesired = desiredPrice;
                underDesired *= 1.16;
                underDesired -= 1.28;
                result = underDesired / gramPrice;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (breakpoint == 3.5) {
            result = eighthWeight;
            break;
        }
        if (breakpoint == 7) {
            result = quarterWeight;
            break;
        }
        if (breakpoint == 14) {
            result = halfWeight;
            break;
        }
        if (breakpoint == 28) {
            result = ounceWeight;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (neededGrams < breakpoint) {
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (result < weightFormat[i]) {
                continue;
            } else if (result >= weightFormat[i]) {
                newBreak = weightFormat[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (newBreak == 1) {
                result = gramWeight;
                if (result > 1 && result <= 1.99) {
                    underDesired = desiredPrice;
                    underDesired *= 1.16;
                    underDesired -= 1.28;
                    result = underDesired / gramPrice;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (newBreak == 3.5) {
                result = eighthWeight;
                break;
            }
            if (newBreak == 7) {
                result = quarterWeight;
                break;
            }
            if (newBreak == 14) {
                result = halfWeight;
                break;
            }
            if (newBreak == 28) {
                result = ounceWeight;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;

}

public static double getWeight(int input) {
    double result = 0;
    if (input == 5) {

        gramWeight = (desiredPrice / getGramPrice(fivePerGram[0]));
        eighthWeight = (desiredPrice / getEighthPrice(fivePerGram[1]));
        quarterWeight = (desiredPrice / getQuarterPrice(fivePerGram[2]));
        halfWeight = (desiredPrice / getHalfPrice(fivePerGram[3]));
        ounceWeight = (desiredPrice / getOuncePrice(fivePerGram[4]));

        double weightList[] = { gramWeight, eighthWeight, quarterWeight, halfWeight, ounceWeight };

        maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weightList).max().getAsDouble();
        maxWeight = round(maxWeight, 2);

        breakpoint = getBreakpoint(maxWeight);

        neededGrams = getNeededGrams(breakpoint);

    }

    if (input == 8) {

        gramWeight = (desiredPrice / getGramPrice(eightPerGram[0]));
        eighthWeight = (desiredPrice / getEighthPrice(eightPerGram[1]));
        quarterWeight = (desiredPrice / getQuarterPrice(eightPerGram[2]));
        halfWeight = (desiredPrice / getHalfPrice(eightPerGram[3]));
        ounceWeight = (desiredPrice / getOuncePrice(eightPerGram[4]));

        double weightList[] = { gramWeight, eighthWeight, quarterWeight, halfWeight, ounceWeight };

        double maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weightList).max().getAsDouble();
        maxWeight = round(maxWeight, 2);

        breakpoint = getBreakpoint(maxWeight);

        neededGrams = getNeededGrams(breakpoint);

    }

    if (input == 10) {

        gramWeight = (desiredPrice / getGramPrice(tenPerGram[0]));
        eighthWeight = (desiredPrice / getEighthPrice(tenPerGram[1]));
        quarterWeight = (desiredPrice / getQuarterPrice(tenPerGram[2]));
        halfWeight = (desiredPrice / getHalfPrice(tenPerGram[3]));
        ounceWeight = (desiredPrice / getOuncePrice(tenPerGram[4]));

        double weightList[] = { gramWeight, eighthWeight, quarterWeight, halfWeight, ounceWeight };

        double maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weightList).max().getAsDouble();
        maxWeight = round(maxWeight, 2);

        breakpoint = getBreakpoint(maxWeight);

        neededGrams = getNeededGrams(breakpoint);

    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    desiredPrice = getDesired(Integer.parseInt(inputField.getText()));
    if (fiveButton.isSelected()) {
        pricePoint = 5;
    }
    if (eightButton.isSelected()) {
        pricePoint = 8;
    }
    if (tenButton.isSelected()) {
        pricePoint = 10;
    }

    getWeight(pricePoint);

    weightOutput.setText(Double.toString(round(neededGrams, 2)));
    weightOutput.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I ditched the idea of multiple class files

This is the opposite direction to where you should be going. For example, your action listener class, GUI class and business logic should have nothing to do with each other.

Broadly, the accounting operation you're doing here is pretty convoluted and implemented to be much more complex than it needs to be. It's so impenetrable that I can't speak to most of it, and had to translate it (almost) verbatim.

You should not separate your `fivePer`, `eightPer` etc. arrays. This can be a single two-dimensional array (three by five).

Almost all of your GUI element variables should not be class members, and should be local-only.

Don't rely on empty labels to modify layout.

Perhaps you're wondering why your fonts won't work. It's *Comic Sans*, not *Comic Sams*. (I was considering keeping this one to myself to spare your users their eyeballs; alas.)

Your `weightOutput` width is problematic - you're unnecessarily eliding longer strings when there should be plenty of room.

There's a large amount of repetition and redundancy in your code; see for example `getHalfPrice` and family, which all basically do the same thing. You should instead rely on an index into your `weightFormat` to vary your divisor.

I don't think that it's wise to `round()` midway through your financials; you should only round for display at the end.

Many of your variable and function names need love. For instance, does `getDesired` actually account for tax? Because that's what it looks like it does.

`getNeededGrams` is particularly troubled: `input` will always be equal to `breakpoint`, and so the inner condition here:

```
    if (breakpoint == 1) {
        result = gramWeight;
        if (input > 1 && input <= 1.99) {
```

so far as I can tell will never ever be true. That reduces the entire function to one array lookup.

Consider reworking your UI so that there is no calculate button, and any time a control is changed the output is refreshed.

### Suggested

This is not comprehensive, and is only a first step. The results are basically the same as yours but with less intermediate rounding error.

**Gui.java**

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Gui extends JFrame {
    private final JTextField inputField = new JTextField();

    private final JLabel weightOutput = new JLabel("0");

    private final ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();


    public Gui() {
        this.setSize(420, 420);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setResizable(false);

        JPanel
            topPanel = new JPanel(),
            leftPanel = new JPanel(),
            middlePanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel inputLabel = new JLabel("Desired Price"),
            outputLabel = new JLabel("Grams Needed: ");

        JRadioButton
            fiveButton = new JRadioButton("5 / g"),
            eightButton = new JRadioButton("8 / g"),
            tenButton = new JRadioButton("10 / g");

        radioButtonGroup.add(fiveButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(eightButton);
        radioButtonGroup.add(tenButton);

        ChangeListener radioChanges = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent) {
                onChange();
            }
        };

        fiveButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        fiveButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        fiveButton.setForeground(Color.white);
        fiveButton.setFocusable(false);
        fiveButton.setActionCommand("5");
        fiveButton.setSelected(true);
        fiveButton.addChangeListener(radioChanges);

        eightButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        eightButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        eightButton.setForeground(Color.white);
        eightButton.setFocusable(false);
        eightButton.setActionCommand("8");
        eightButton.addChangeListener(radioChanges);

        tenButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(90, 20));
        tenButton.setBackground(Color.black);
        tenButton.setForeground(Color.white);
        tenButton.setFocusable(false);
        tenButton.setActionCommand("10");
        tenButton.addChangeListener(radioChanges);

        outputLabel.setBounds(125, 0, 200, 200);
        outputLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 20));
        outputLabel.setForeground(Color.black);

        weightOutput.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        weightOutput.setBounds(140, 130, 200, 100);
        weightOutput.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 40));
        weightOutput.setVisible(false);
        weightOutput.setForeground(Color.green);

        inputLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        inputLabel.setForeground(Color.white);
        inputLabel.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 11));
        inputLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { onChange(); }
            @Override public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { onChange(); }
            @Override public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { onChange(); }
        };

        inputField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 20));
        inputField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
        inputField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(listener);

        topPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        topPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.black);
        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        leftPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        leftPanel.add(inputLabel);
        leftPanel.add(inputField);
        leftPanel.add(fiveButton);
        leftPanel.add(eightButton);
        leftPanel.add(tenButton);

        middlePanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        middlePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(370, 320));
        middlePanel.add(outputLabel);
        middlePanel.add(weightOutput);
        middlePanel.setLayout(null);

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(middlePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Gui();
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }

    public void onChange() {
        try {
            double price = Double.parseDouble(inputField.getText());

            int pricePoint = Integer.parseInt(
                radioButtonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand()
            );

            Order order = new Order(price, pricePoint);

            weightOutput.setText(Double.toString(round(order.neededWeight, 2)));
            weightOutput.setVisible(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            weightOutput.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}
```

**Order.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/*
Selected example output

      4     20       100     200     999

5    .69    4.02     30.17   60.34   301.42

8     -     2.16     14.2    30.17   150.71

10    -     1.72
* */

public class Order {
    private static final List<Integer> pricePoints = List.of(5, 8, 10);

    private static final int[][] pricePerWeight = new int[][] {
        {  5, 15, 25,  40,  80 },
        {  8, 25, 45,  85, 160 },
        { 10, 35, 65, 120, 225 }
    };

    private static final double[] weightFormat = new double[] {
        1, 3.5, 7, 14, 28
    };


    public final double price, desiredPrice, maxWeight, breakpoint, neededWeight;
    public final int pricePoint, pricePointIndex, breakpointIndex;

    public Order(double price, int pricePoint) {
        this.price = price;
        this.pricePoint = pricePoint;

        desiredPrice = price / 1.16;
        pricePointIndex = pricePoints.indexOf(pricePoint);

        double[] weights = getWeights();
        maxWeight = Arrays.stream(weights).max().getAsDouble();

        breakpointIndex = getBreakpointIndex();

        if (breakpointIndex >= 0) {
            breakpoint = weightFormat[breakpointIndex];
            neededWeight = weights[breakpointIndex];
        }
        else {
            breakpoint = 0;
            neededWeight = 0;
        }
    }

    private double[] getWeights() {
        double[] weights = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            weights[i] = desiredPrice / (
                pricePerWeight[pricePointIndex][i]
                / weightFormat[i]
            );
        }

        return weights;
    }

    private int getBreakpointIndex() {
        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (maxWeight >= weightFormat[i])
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, I have never messed with 2d arrays before, so it never crossed my mind. Seems obvious now. Doing some tests against my POS, ive noticed I end up a couple pennies off on some tests, assumption is thats a result of rounding all my math before calculation. My getNeededGrams method has that odd if statement between 1 && 1.99 because of some odd thing in my POS in which is wont charge 16% between those weight, just a flat rate of $.128. And the redundency of that is because if the neededGrams ends up lower than the initial breakpoint, the price/gram changes. Tysm for input